# How do I accept arbitrary query parameters in a Restler GET request?

Tags: php, restler

I have a basic CRUD endpoint, and I want to be able to search by arbitrary fields in my database.  Is there a way to allow this without specifying every possible filter in the method signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the built in $_GET[] super global.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use query parameters to solve this. So just accept the fields like `example.com/api/people/?name=John&age=20`

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to support arbitrary query parameters.  Restler requires me to specify every possible query parameter in the method signature.  On tables with 20+ columns, this isn't really feasable or necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to document them, you can use $request_data as a parameter, this will get all the data that is sent to the API

Comment: This works for POST requests, but I didn't have any luck with GET parameters.  I ended up just reading from the $_GET[] structure.